# Как загрузить словарь? Python в sqlite3 таблицу?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3

Есть таблица `sqlite3`, в ней 3 столбца (условно "A", "B" и "C") и 100+ строк.

Столбцы `A` и `B` уже заполнены, столбец `A` является `Unique` и используется как ключ.

Я получаю данные из таблицы, выполняю с ними определенные действия и хочу заполнить столбец `C` результатом.

Мой код (упрощенно, вырезал все лишнее):

```
    # records_list = {}
    records_list = []
    try:
        sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
        cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()
        print("БД Успешно подключена к SQLite")

        sqlite_select_query = """SELECT DISTINCT B FROM table;""" # LIMIT 5;""" # - использовалось для тестов

        for record in сursor.execute(sqlite_select_query).fetchall():
            # records_list[record[0]] = do_work(record[0])
            records_list.append((do_work(record[0]), record[0]))
 
# do_work() - условная функция, выполняющая все необходимые действия со значением из столбца B
# в дальнейшем результат do_work'а будет записан в столбец C

        print('Ура! Я выполнил первую часть!')

        if records_list: # я проверил, что словарь не пуст
            sqlite_update_query = """UPDATE table SET C = ? WHERE B = ?"""
            cursor.executemany(sqlite_update_query, records_list)
            sqlite_connection.commit()
            print("Записей", cursor.rowcount, ". Успешно обновлены")
            sqlite_connection.commit()
        else:
            print("Список пуст")

        cursor.close()

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Ошибка при работе с sqlite:", error)

    finally:
        if sqlite_connection:
            sqlite_connection.close()
            print("Соединение с SQLite закрыто")
```

Для теста добавляю в `SELECT`  `LIMIT 5`.

По результатам при попытке исполнения в выводе я вижу вот такое:

```
Ура! Я выполнил первую часть!
Ошибка при работе с sqlite: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 432 supplied.
Соединение с SQLite закрыто
```

Насколько я понял, нужно то ли как то переделать мой словарь (в не-словарь?), то ли саму команду `executemany`. Но никак не получается найти/сообразить чего именно и как это сделать правильно.

А еще меня смущает - откуда он в словаре из 5 пар (`limit 5` же) - нашел 432 чего то там?

По идее, конечно, можно загнать в цикл по `records_list` и делать 100+ отдельных `UPDATE`, но это кажется не правильным решением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался сам.

Нужно было использовать не словарь, а `List`.

Закомментировал в вопросе неправильные строки (для понимания моего косяка и поиска) и написал под ними правильные. Изменению подверглась верхняя часть программы.

Было:

```
records_list = {}
...
records_list[record[0]] = do_work(record[0])
```

Стало:

```
records_list = []
...
records_list.append((do_work(record[0]), record[0])) # Внимание на количество скобочек!!!
```